# Who provides the p.a?

Tags: equipment, band

I hope this is acceptable - it is about musical practice after all.

In a band situation (where a lot of us are or have been), who is expected to provide the p.a? Obviously on quite large gigs, it's provided - that's not a problem. But there are many occasions when one's not available, so apart from hiring is the question.

All the instrumentalists will have to provide their own instruments, at varying costs and portability, but who owns the p.a. is a question that has just popped up again. A vocalist forming a new band has neither p.a. nor mic. and I'm appealing for experienced band players to share whether bands they are, or have been in, would have a shared p.a. or does the vocalist own it. If it's shared, surely it becomes problematic should one member leave? Or - worse still - "yes, you can join but it'll cost you for a share in our p.a..."

Comment: Are you asking about gigs or rehearsal? Both the answer and the PAs are likely to be different. Or are you curious about both situations?

Comment: Related thread: [What are the steps involved in organizing a new band?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/99056/70803).

Comment: Why are you asking about the vocalist? Don't the other instruments need PA and monitors too?

Comment: @user1079505 - I was considering the bands I've worked with where the vocalist just turns up and asks "where's my mic?" My reply was usually "still in the shop, you obviously haven't bought it yet" And yes, others use the p.a. too, but in a way, they 'make use of' my k'bds, gtr, bass, drums, when I gig with them.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - both, really. Gigs mainly. In a rehearsal situation, I can get away with some bands singing without mics (yes!), but then the instrumentalists still have to provide instruments, but vox turns up with nothing!

Comment: Does "p.a." mean "public address system" here?

Comment: @TannerSwett - yes. Public Address.

Comment: This sort of seems like a survey question. Like you’re taking a poll to see how bands handle PAs. What am I not understanding that makes this question objective and answerable?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - it's answerable - by those who have the experiences. I am wondering - and have done for ever - what the general consensus is about p.a. ownership and responsibility. Where better to ask than here, where so many have band experience, and can provide their own stories. I'm also trying to provide some wherewithall to a singer who wants to form a new band, but I'm reticent to be the p.a. guy as well as arranger, player and backing singer, while he may be happy to tag along with little, or no, contribution gear-wise. The answers so far have been enlightening, including yours.

Comment: Yeah… my understanding is that SE is more about questions that have a single, verifiable, correct answer, or at least a narrow class of correct answers. The word “consensus” also seems like a poll, to me.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - you may well be correct. However, there are many questions here in similar vein, which must have guided players who become band members, with very useful points and anecdotes. And the 'practice' part surely gives licence for that sort of query. With 750 views so far, it's obviously of interest to more than a few. And to feature as a top question... shame to see it go.

Comment: Voting to keep open. My understanding is that the question was hoping for "oh yeah, it's common knowledge that it's always ___." Questions about such functional practices ought to be on topic, like "Who gives the pitch to tune an ensemble?" (Answer can then discuss symphony orchestra vs piano qt vs early music band.) In this case the answer *happened to be* "shrug, there's no common practice," but there might have been one.

Comment: @AndyBonner - thank you for your support. I feel that if this question is closed, there's a proportion of the site lost to musicians. But there are plenty of zealots out there.

Answer (score 7):

I guess it depends, maybe no two will be the same…

I used to work occasionally for a function band who commanded enough money for a show that they just hired a PA, lighting rig & engineer/roadies each time.
I mean, who's got room in their garage for a 5k rig & all the lighting too… who is also happy to lug it themselves to every gig?

Every smaller band I've ever been in bought their own, between them, then if anyone left or joined, the rig still belonged to the band. You leave it behind if you move on, but the guy replacing you gets free, temporary usage.
If the outfit disbands completely, whoever is left at that point who contributed originally gets a share of the sale price.

I've heard of singers owning their own; also I've worked solo, me plus guitar  & backing tracks & had my own little rig that would work for pubs/small clubs, but I've never shifted it up to a full band.

Comment: Actually, I did just that! Looked after a big rig, for B'ham Jazz - artistes from all over the world - and humped it all, set it all up, ran the desk, and stored it! Younger then though... And never got a penny for it. foolish as well, maybe - but that was different, as BJ generated enough money to buy it all, so not the same scenario. I can imagine your 4th & 5th  para. would cause many upsets!

Comment: My nephew started out with a couple of lights he could use at the local am dram, for free, just so he could join in, as he can't act, can't sing & his sister can do both. She gave it up eventually, he runs rigs across half the big theatres in the North now. No longer fits in a garage, 40' trucks these days ;)) [I've never known anyone leave a band & want their share of the rig back, but I can imagine it happening]

Answer (score 7):

I have been in bands with a variety of arrangements regarding sound reinforcement equipment.  Some rented PA systems for gigs where there was no house system.  In other cases, one member owned a PA and shared while each vocalist (who also happened to be an instrumentalist) owned their own microphone.  There's no "standard" approach, and each band member is likely to come to the table with their own tacit assumptions!

So, I think your question is a subset of a larger issue that bands need to be aware of:  The need to have some kind of agreement in place when you join.  In addition to equipment ownership issues, a band agreement can also cover things like:

- Responsibility for storage and transportation of equipment.
- Ownership of copyright on band compositions/arrangements.
- Whether the band is fully egalitarian, or has "leader"
- Whether the leader has the right to terminate other members.
- Whether some majority of members can terminate another member.
- Who owns the name, logo, etc.

Agreeing upon these things early in the band's existence can help avoid animosity, resentment, legal or financial battles, etc.

There are standard forms available online for band agreements. Here's one example (not an endorsement): [Sample Band Agreement](https://www.musicbizacademy.com/knab/articles/bandagreementsample.htm)

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far, which is "there is no one answer, you need to figure this out between you and make sure everybody agrees and there are no surprises".

Comment: @JörgWMittag - there probably is no one answer. I'm searching for the experience of contributors to this site, myself having been in many bands over the last 60 odd yrs, with many different arrangements. But the one that rankles most is a vocalist with nothing of his own. Reading ideas will also help others forming bands, and maybe avoiding the situations we find where some poor guy has the responsibility of their own gear, and then the p.a. on top of that. Pretty unfair in my book.

Comment: @Tim If you think of it as a business arrangement, then the person on the losing end of the unfairness has a responsibility to themselves to work to mitigate it.  Splitting the cost of a rental PA might help the members understand the value of one owned by a member.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm appealing for experienced band players to share whether bands they are, or have been in, would have a shared p.a. or does the vocalist own it.

My experience is "neither". Either no one in the band has owned a PA or I’ve owned the PA, as the guitarist, or another non-vocalist has owned a PA in their house. In one of my bands, the only gear we used that I didn’t own was the drum kit (owned by the drummer) and anything provided by venues.

Specific situations include:

- Every practice with drums is at a practice space with PA included in the hourly rate - rate split evenly among members.
- One band member (usually the drummer) has a practice space in their house or garage and one member (usually the drummer or me) has a PA or at least monitors set up in that space.
- We shared a practice space with another band and the other band owned the PA and let us use it.

For gigs it’s mostly been the venue has a PA already set up, but I’ve been in bands that had to hire a PAs for some gigs. Even if we had one at the practice space it usually wasn’t big enough and worth the hassle to gig with it.

I rehearsed maybe 2-4 times with a vocalist who had a mic and a powered speaker kinda like a musician with an amp, but he was a coke fiend and that last about two weeks.

Note that I was only ever seriously in one band that had a dedicated vocalist. Every other band the singer(s) also played instruments. So there wasn’t much split between singers and players. Most of us both sang and played. I owned a PA because I was an *engineer*, not because I sang. Add a mix engineer to the band and you should be set. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this. I was considering more the situation where the singer did just that. It complicates it more when the vox also plays an instrument! I have several p.as, but am reticent to add one to the gear I already have to lug about, set up, break down, and store. Let alone repair when something breaks.